# Search-As-You-Type with Redis ("includes" type search not "starts with" type search)

Tags: search, redis, autocomplete

I'm developing a search-as-you-type feature using Redis. The type of search that I need is an “*includes*” type search and **not** a “*starts with*” type search. I already know that ZRANGEBYLEX would be perfect for a “*starts with*” search but it won’t work for what I need. For example, if the user types “a”, they will see “**A**lly”, “**a**vril”, “D**a**ve" and “Lind**a**”.  If they type, “av”, they will see  “**av**ril” and “D**av**e”. The search also needs to be case-insensitive and return N results, sorted alphabetically.

1. Is there any way to beat linear time for this type of search?
2. If not, do you see any way of optimizing the following linear-time algorithm?

To store:

- Create a set key called “users”
- For each user, SADD "users" "{lowercase username}:{original username}"

To search:

- run SCARD to get the size of the set
- run a single SSCAN with MATCH on lowercase search term (and specify a COUNT greater than the SCARD) to get all matches
- get rid of the lowercase usernames from each entry that was matched
- sort the results alphabetically
- return the top N results

Some further considerations:
The maximum number of users will be under 20,000. That is why I just do a single SSCAN and don’t loop it, using the cursor.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can build a n-gram index with sorted set:

The n-gram list for *Ally* is:

- *a*, *al*, *all*, *ally*
- *l*, *ll*, *lly*
- *l*, *ly*
- *y*

For each n-gram, call `ZADD` to add an item to the sorted set. Each item is consist of 3 parts:

```
n-gram-in-lowercase : word-in-lowercase : original-word
```

For example:

```
zadd kkk 0 a:ally:Ally 0 al:ally:Ally 0 all:ally:Ally 0 ally:ally:Ally
zadd kkk 0 l:ally:Ally 0 ll:ally:Ally 0 lly:ally:Ally
zadd kkk 0 l:ally:Ally 0 ly:ally:Ally
zadd kkk 0 y:ally:Ally
```

After indexing all words, you can use the `ZRANGEBYLEX` command to do the search:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> zrangebylex kkk [a "[a\xff" limit 0 10
 1) "a:ally:Ally"
 2) "a:avril:avril"
 3) "a:dave:Dave"
 4) "a:linda:Linda"
 5) "al:ally:Ally"
 6) "all:ally:Ally"
 7) "ally:ally:Ally"
 8) "av:avril:avril"
 9) "av:dave:Dave"
10) "ave:dave:eDave"
```

***The result is SORTED, but might contains duplicate items, so you need to remove these duplicate items on the client side.***

This solution will build a very big index, and there's another solution that can reduce the index size with extra work to do on the client side: **only index part of the n-gram index**:

```
zadd k 0 ally:Ally
zadd k 0 lly:Ally
zadd k 0 ly:Ally
zadd k 0 y:Ally
```

When searching, the result of `ZRANGEBYLEX` command ***is NOT SORTED and MIGHT have duplicate items***. So you need to remove the duplicate items and sort the result on the client side. Also, because it's not sorted, you cannot use the `LIMIT offset count` options, and have to retrieve all matched items to find out the top N matched items.